# Caching JSON actions in Rails with caches_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, caching

I am having trouble caching a JSON action in my Rails controller. What happens is that, from an Android app, I make a request to the endpoint specifying the mime type `"application/json"` in the header but the response comes as `"text/html"`.

This is the only action I have that uses `caches_action`, and I am using `caches_action` so my filters aren't skipped (like in `pages_action`).

I'm using:

```
caches_action :cards, expires_in: 1.day,
               cache_path: "mobile/cards/card_id_#{params[:card_id]}"
```

It works if I append `.json` to the request url, but I don't wanna do that, since all other JSON endpoints in this application do not require that.

Why does Rails force the response to be served as `"text/html"`?

What could I be possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem just by adding `format: :json` to the route, as told by the [official documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActionController/Caching/Actions.html):

> The :format parameter is taken into account though. The safest way to cache by MIME type is to pass the format in the route.

Comment: Hey @rodrigoalves, can you be more descriptive? Perhaps provide an example?

Comment: Hi, an example would be `resources :posts, format: :json`.